# MPMoviePlayerController dismissing full screen mode not working in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

The `MPMoviePlayerController` working fine in iPad with iOS 5, initially the video starts by adding `MPMoviePlayerController` to subview of self at certain frame .Pressing full screen button on `MPMoviePlayerController` embedded controls displaying the movie in full screen,again tapping the button will bring the video back to the initial frame in iOS 5. But in iOS 6, the when I press full screen button to bring the video to initial frame, the video just gone out of screen. Looks like Apple has made some undocumented change to `MPMoviePlayer` class that is causing this weird behaviour. Anyone having the fix for this?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. What a pain in the backside, and took a while to figure out with my app...

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed this issue myself, in iOS 6, apple has made some undocumented changes to `MPMoviePLayerController` class, when you tap on full screen button, the `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisAppear` gets called for both the controller launching `MPMoviePLayerController` and its ParentController.

In My Project (a pdf reader), I have a very complex view hierarchy, adding a reader in view Controller, then adding the readerPageContents buttons(image Gallery, video, link) to reader page and then playing video on video button tap.So it was calling the ViewWillDisappear and `ViewDidDisappear` when launching the video in full screen, and when when I press toggle screen button to bring the video to initial frame, the `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear` of both controllers called again and I was creating the pdf page again in parent's controller viewDidAppear which was removing the video.

So easier fix it to avoid `ViewDidDisappear` and `ViewWillDisappear` gets called by setting some `BOOL`.

Comment: This solution works for me too. Although, technically iOS 6 MPMoviePlayerController behaviour sounds like it is fixing a bug in prior iOS versions, as those views are in fact dissappearing.

Comment: Actually i'd like to add, my app runs fine in iOS 5 and iOS 6, however when I re-compile it against iOS 6 SDK, that's when I experience the problem. So this MPMoviePlayerController change by Apple, does seem to be backwards compatible for existing apps, but not for apps recompiled. Very clever.